# Active record intermittent count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails method that is failing to count rows in a relation.

I have simplified the problem to the following trivial example.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.how_many(anything)
    anything.count
  end
end

a = User.last.groups
a.class
 => Group::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy
a.count
 => 1

b = Group.where(id: 1)
b.class
 => Group::ActiveRecord_Relation
b.count
 => 1
```

With the above initiated I get the following results:

```
a.how_many(b)
 => 1

b.how_many(a)
 => 0

b.how_many(a.to_a)
 => 1

a.how_many(a)
 => 1

b.how_many(b)
 => 1
```

i have just discovered that when a is cast to an array then the answer is correct as per the third example above.

Comment: I am having problem to know what is it that you are trying to accomplish

Comment: This is a simplified trivial version of a more complex method that suffers the same problem. The questions I have is why does the second example above return a count of zero?